# .caf vs .wav in iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos2d and it is possible to play both formats using SimpleAudioEngine (obviously did not tried .caf) What format is preferable and why ?

Comment: Depends on your needs, tools, ... Here are CAF advantages: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CAFSpec/CAF_overview/CAF_overview.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001862-CH209-BCGDADFA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use caf format with IMA4 compression for sound effects and aac for BGM.

- [CocosDenshion FAQ - What sound formats can I use?](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion%3afaq)

> For sound effects played with
>   CDSoundEngine it is recommended to use
>   16 bit mono wave files for
>   uncompressed audio and IMA4 for lossy
>   compressed audio. IMA4 sounds are
>   around one quarter the size of the
>   corresponding wave file.

- [How do I choose the best audio formats in iPhone OS?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/index.html#PLAYBACK-CHOOSE_THE_BEST_AUDIO_FORMATS_IN_IPHONE_OS)